# Error:(1) Error parsing XML: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect. What's wrong?

Tags: android, xml, encoding, utf-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.molitveniseznamkackrko.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code. Error points to the first line. If I use utf-16, then app runs in emulator, but I can't build apk file (Error:(1) Error: utf-16: Not using UTF-8 as the file encoding. This can lead to subtle bugs with non-ascii characters [EnforceUTF8]). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure, there is no empty line/space on top

Comment: There is none. If it may help, this error started to appear when I wanted to have custom TTF font. I have then decided to not use custom font.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. I have copied everything execpt `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and made new layout file and paste it there. And it works now. Still don't know what was a problem, but it doesn't really matter.